# ViewModel using Database Room error Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, android-livedata

I'm currently facing an error, where  the home fragment and using viewmodel, recyclerview to implement CRUD. the error is where I'm login using id and password in loginfragment, it appears error and the error says that cannot create instance of class NoteViewModel, and i dont know where part is wrong

this is homefragment

```
package com.example.challenge4binar

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.SharedPreferences
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.viewModels
import androidx.navigation.findNavController
import com.example.challenge4binar.databinding.FragmentHomeBinding

// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "param1"
private const val ARG_PARAM2 = "param2"

/**
 * A simple [Fragment] subclass.
 * Use the [HomeFragment.newInstance] factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private var param1: String? = null
    private var param2: String? = null
    private var _binding: FragmentHomeBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private lateinit var sharedPreferences: SharedPreferences

    private val noteViewModel: NoteViewModel by viewModels()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {
            param1 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM1)
            param2 = it.getString(ARG_PARAM2)
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        _binding = FragmentHomeBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        sharedPreferences = requireContext().getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        return binding.root
    }

    companion object {
        /**
         * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
         * this fragment using the provided parameters.
         *
         * @param param1 Parameter 1.
         * @param param2 Parameter 2.
         * @return A new instance of fragment HomeFragment.
         */
        // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
        @JvmStatic
        fun newInstance(param1: String, param2: String) =
            HomeFragment().apply {
                arguments = Bundle().apply {
                    putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1)
                    putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2)
                }
            }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding.tvLogout.setOnClickListener {
            it.findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_homeFragment_to_loginFragment)
        }
        val adapter = NoteAdapter(requireContext(), noteViewModel, mutableListOf())

        val recyclerView = binding.rvNote
        recyclerView.adapter = adapter

        noteViewModel.allNotes.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { notes ->
            if (notes.isEmpty()) {
                binding.tvDatakosong.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.rvNote.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                binding.tvDatakosong.visibility = View.GONE
                binding.rvNote.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                adapter.setNotes(notes)
            }
        }

        binding.btnTambahHome.setOnClickListener{
            dialogtambah()
        }
    }

    fun dialogtambah() {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext())
        val inflater = layoutInflater
        val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tambah, null)

        builder.setView(dialogView)
        builder.setTitle("Tambah Data")

        builder.setPositiveButton("Add") { dialog, _ ->
            val contentEditText = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_judul_tambah)
            val titleEditText = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_catatan_tambah)
            val notecontent = contentEditText.text.toString()
            val titlenote = titleEditText.text.toString()

            if (notecontent.isNotEmpty() && titlenote.isNotEmpty()) {
                val newNote = Note(note = notecontent, title = titlenote)
                noteViewModel.insert(newNote)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is noteviewmodel

```
package com.example.challenge4binar

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.viewModelScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch

class NoteViewModel(private val repository: NoteRepository):ViewModel() {

    val allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>> =repository.allNotes

    fun insert(note: Note) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(note)
    }

    fun update(note:Note) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.update(note)
    }

    fun delete(note:Note) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.delete(note)
    }
}
```

this is noteRepository

```
package com.example.challenge4binar

import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData

class NoteRepository(private val noteDao: NoteDao) {

    val allNotes: LiveData<List<Note>> = noteDao.getAllNotes()

    suspend fun insert(note: Note){
        noteDao.insert(note)
    }

    suspend fun update(note:Note){
        noteDao.update(note)
    }

    suspend fun delete (note:Note){
        noteDao.delete(note)
    }
}
```

this is Note

```
@Entity(tableName = "notes")
data class Note(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)val id:Long = 0,
    var title:String,
    var note:String
)
```

and this is noteadapter

```
package com.example.challenge4binar

import android.app.AlertDialog
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.ImageView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class NoteAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val noteViewModel: NoteViewModel,
    private val notes: MutableList<Note>):RecyclerView.Adapter<NoteAdapter.ViewHolder>() {


    inner class ViewHolder(itemView: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val deleteButton : ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_delete_rv)
        val updateButton :ImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_update_rv)

        fun bind(note: Note){
            deleteButton.setOnClickListener{
                dialoghapus(note)

            }
            updateButton.setOnClickListener {
                dialogupdate(note)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): NoteAdapter.ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.delete, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NoteAdapter.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val note = notes[position]
        holder.bind(note)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return notes.size
    }

    private fun dialoghapus(note: Note) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setTitle("Delete Note")

        builder.setPositiveButton("Delete") { dialog, _ ->
            noteViewModel.delete(note)

            val position = notes.indexOf(note)
            if (position != -1) {
                notes.removeAt(position)
                notifyItemRemoved(position)
            }
            dialog.dismiss()
        }

        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel") { dialog, _ ->
            dialog.dismiss()
        }
        builder.show()
    }

    private fun dialogupdate(note: Note) {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)
        val dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.update, null)

        // Use var instead of val for these variables
        var etJudul = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_judul_edit)
        var etCatatan = dialogView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_catatan_edit)
        val btnInput = dialogView.findViewById<Button>(R.id.btn_edit)

        etJudul.setText(note.title)
        etCatatan.setText(note.note)

        builder.setView(dialogView)
        builder.setTitle("Update Note")

        val dialog = builder.create()

        btnInput.setOnClickListener {
            // Handle the update logic here
            val updatedTitle = etJudul.text.toString()
            val updatedNote = etCatatan.text.toString()

            if (updatedTitle.isNotEmpty() && updatedNote.isNotEmpty()) {
                // Update the note with the new data
                note.title = updatedTitle
                note.note = updatedNote

                // Call your update method or ViewModel function here
                // For example: noteViewModel.update(note)

                // Dismiss the dialog when the update is done
                dialog.dismiss()
            } else {
                // Display an error message or handle empty fields
            }
        }

        dialog.show()
    }
    fun setNotes(newNotes: List<Note>){
        notes.clear()
        notes.addAll(newNotes)
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are passing the NoteRepository to the NoteViewModel constructor and using delegate function to instantiate the viewModel in the fragment, so it will not get any reference to it.

You will need a ViewModelFactory for it then,
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel/viewmodel-factories

Updated:

**NoteRepository**

```
class NoteRepository {
    fun checkWorking() {
        Log.d("NoteViewModel_Check", "checkWorking: ")
    }
}
```

**NoteViewModel**

```
class NoteViewModel(private val repository: NoteRepository) : ViewModel() {
    fun checkWorking() {
        repository.checkWorking()
    }

}
```

**NoteViewModelFactory**

```
class NoteViewModelFactory(private val noteRepository: NoteRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(NoteViewModel::class.java)) {
            return NoteViewModel(noteRepository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel")
    }

}
```

Usage:
**MainActivity**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val noteViewModel by viewModels<NoteViewModel> { NoteViewModelFactory(NoteRepository()) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        noteViewModel.checkWorking()
}
}
```

Let me know, if you are still facing the issues.

**Update 2:**

Just replace this in your **HomeFragment**, you will find the log in the LogCat

```
val database by lazy { AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext()) }
val noteDao by lazy { database!!.noteDao() }
```

Comment: I just Make the viewmodel factory like this
```
class NoteViewModelFactory(
    private val repository: NoteRepository,
    private val application: Application
):ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    @Suppress("unchecked_cast")
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(NoteViewModel::class.java)){
            return NoteViewModel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown Viewmodel Class")
    }
}
```

and still it force close when i log in

Comment: and use this in home fragment

val database = AppDatabase.getDatabase(requireContext())
    val noteDao = database?.noteDao()

    private val noteViewModel: NoteViewModel by viewModels{
        noteDao?.let { dao ->
            val noteRepository = NoteRepository(noteDao = dao)
            NoteViewModelFactory(noteRepository, requireActivity().application)
        } ?: throw IllegalStateException("Database is null")
    }

Comment: Can you please update this code into the question? It's hard to read here.

Comment: it still error, and i cannot find the tag in the log cat
this is my repository if you wanna check out my code https://github.com/PACE1000/Note

Comment: Check my updated answer above

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass data directly to viewModel, You have to make viewModelFactory that will receive data and will create a ViewModel object for you. then you can use that viewmodel object in your fragment or activity. There are plenty of resources available over the internet about viewmodel and viewmodel factory.