# How can I access the viewmodel of a fragment from another fragment?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, viewmodel

I am new to Kotlin and am trying to integrate a Room Database. The Main activity holds several fragments, one of the called TestFragment. This Fragment shall list the dao's of a repository and has a button to open another fragment, called NewItemFragment, that (if it would work) opens a bottomsheet dialog to add a new TestItem to the database. Both share the same viewModel.

In TestFragment, a view model is instantiated, while a NewTestFragment is instantiated when pressing the newItemButton.

```
class TestFragment : Fragment(), TestItemClickListener {

    // connect the fragment to its xml
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentTestBinding
    private val testViewModel: TestViewModel by viewModels {
        TestItemModelFactory((requireActivity().application as TestApplication).repository)
    }
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentTestBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.newItemButton.setOnClickListener {
            NewTestFragment(null).show(requireActivity().supportFragmentManager, "newTestTag")
        }
        setRecyclerView()

    }
...
```

As far as I understand, the NewTestFragment is attached to mainActivity.

```
class TestApplication : Application()
{
    private val database by lazy { TestItemDatabase.getDatabase(this) } // initialize database
    val repository by lazy { TestItemRepository(database.testItemDao()) } // initialize repo
}
```

As soon as the viewModel is accessed in oncreateview in the NewItemFragment, it crashes. -.-

```
class NewItemFragment(var testItem: TestItem?) : BottomSheetDialogFragment() {

    private lateinit var binding: FragmentNewItemBinding //connect the XML!
    private lateinit var  testViewModel: TestViewModel //get the viewmodel for transferring data
    
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater,
                              container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        binding = FragmentNewItemBinding.inflate(inflater,container,false)
        testViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(TestViewModel ::class.java)
        return binding.root
    }
```

The viewmodel-class is instantiated with a repository and just holds a list of live data:

```
class TestViewModel(
    private val repository: TestItemRepository
): ViewModel()
{
    val testItems: LiveData<List<TestItem>> = repository.allTestItems.asLiveData()
}
```

```
class TestItemModelFactory(
    private val repository: TestItemRepository
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory
{
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(TestViewModel::class.java))
            return TestViewModel(repository) as T

        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.testApp.debug, PID: 29127
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.testApp.ui.Test.TestViewModel
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: com.testApp.ui.Test.TestViewModel.<init> []
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3325)  
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:3063)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:202)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:324)
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:306) 
at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.kt:280)
at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.kt:128) 
...
```

From what I understand, the viewmodel is instantiated by first usage, i.e. in NewItemFragment::onCreateView. Obviously, that does not work and I am not sure whether I am doing sth wrong with the factory,mixing up where fragments are attached or with the viewmodel in general.

**Update:** I included a function "checkWorking()" in the repository (got that idea from [ViewModel using Database Room error Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77381956/viewmodel-using-database-room-error-android-studio):

```
fun checkWorking() {
        Log.d("NoteViewModel_Check", "checkWorking: passed")
    }
```

as well as in the viewmodel:

```
fun checkWorking() {
        repository.checkWorking()
    }
```

Output is:

```
com.testApp.debug                  D  checkWorking: passed
```

So obviously, the viewmodel is instantiated and working. It just cannot be accessed in NewItemFragment. I simply have no clue, why.

Answer (score 0):

In your `NewItemFragment` you should initalize your viewmodel with the following syntax:

```kotlin
private val testViewModel: TestViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Also remove this line from your `onCreateView` method.

```kotlin
testViewModel = ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(TestViewModel ::class.java)
```

It might also be worth checking out this codelab!
https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-training-shared-viewmodel#0